# Issue trying to build an action on google when a dialogflow agent existing previosly with intents and entities

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

i really appreciate your help. I have created an action project on google and when i try to build an action the page redirect to an existing dialogflow agent that i have created previously in my GCP project, when i try to test some intent with google assitant it fire an error, i will attach the images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLDRw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2OmM.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages it seems as if the error is in parameters. When you try to test a dialogflow agent, it first checks for validity of all the data and runs the test only if everything is valid. If you are using fulfillment then this is not the case. But based on your images, I assume that you are not using fulfillment.

What you need to do is check your parameters and values, also check these parameters in Intents. When importing a project from some other project, this processes breaks some of the links. I had previously run into this and the only resolution is reverifying your variables wherever you have used them. In intents you would notice them highlighted in different color.